# opencart seo friendly URLs not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, opencart

im having a problem setting up SEO URLs with my Opencart 1.5.5.1

i have enabled seo urls from the opencart admin, renamed the htaccess.txt to .htaccess and also set all the keywords on products and categories.

but still i see the normal urls in my store, not SEO friendly ones. I have contacted my webhost to see if mod_rewrite is enabled, they confirmed it has been enabled.

i thought its a problem with my theme i reverted to the default theme but still nothing works

can someone tell me what might the problem?

Comment: Read & follow this Tutorials for SEO URL: (Hope, helpfully for you.) http://cartadvisor.com/blog/2013/09/12/how-to-turn-on-seo-friendly-urls-in-opencart/

Comment: @HarnishDesign i tried all those but still doesnt work :(

Comment: @LiveEn Did you ever fixed this? I've got the same issue and it drives me mad.